# Separate background color of full width DIV containing two columns

Tags: html, css

I'm using the twitter bootstrap and I am having a hard time figuring out how to separate the background color of two columns that are inside of a main container div, yet have it go full-width.

Here is a fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/seeplanet/ZTbwz/

My main problem is that I want to have the two columns centered on the page and not extending to either side. That is why I have the max-width set on the container.

My HTML:

```
<div id="featured-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9">                          
            Featured Video or Image Gallery     
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">  
             Other Information              
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#featured-content {
background-color: #c7591f;
padding: 20px 0px;
}

.container {
max-width: 960px;
margin:0 auto;
}

.col-sm-9{
 width:75%;   
 float:left;
 background:yellow;
}

.col-sm-3{
 width:25%;
 float:left;
}
}
```

And this is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:table;` to your container like this:

```
.container {
    max-width: 360px;   /* If I remove this, then it works, but then my content is not centered */
    margin:0 auto;
    display:table;
}
```

JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/grrenier/3TE4X/1/

Try this other JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/grrenier/3TE4X/2/

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to make any difference when I added it. It worked for you?

Comment: Yes it worked for me, in your fiddle. If you want to center the content the best way is using display:table and margin:0 auto;

Comment: I've already centered the content. I want that yellow background to extend all the way to the edge of the browser while at the same time keeping the content centered.

Comment: I think that you can set the height or min-height of col-sm-9 element to extend it to the edge of the browser.

Comment: Sorry, but I need it to extend to the LEFT side.

Comment: Thanks for the try Ragnar, but you are not understanding my problem. Take a look at the above screenshot I gave. See the two shades of orange? They extend the full width of the browser. In your examples (and mine) the yellow background doesn't extend the full width.

Comment: Thanks Ragnar! The fiddle looks great. I am having an issue where it breaks the responsiveness, but I can look into that a bit later.